# PHP вывести значение между XML тэгами

Tags: php, xml, парсер, xmlparser

Есть xml тэг

```
$xml = '<id>2</id>
<UniqueIdentificationNumber>MyExampleNumber1</UniqueIdentificationNumber>';
```

Как с помощью php вывести значение изнутри  ?
Учитывая что значения могут меняться, т.к может быть MyExampleNumber2, MyexampleNumber99 и тд.

Comment: Использовать библиотеку для парсинга xml-файлов.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ, я уже нашел способ средствами обычного php

Answer (score 1):

```
$htmltag = 'div';
$string = '<div>Hello</div>';
function htmlParse ($htmltag, $string) {
    $pattern = "#<\s*?$htmltag\b[^>]*>(.*?)</$htmltag\b[^>]*>#s";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

return htmlParse($htmltag, $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Удобнее было бы, вместо получения массива с последующим обращением к одному из его элементов, сразу получать искомую подстроку. Таким образом, код вашей функции станет компактнее:

```
echo htmlParse('div', '<div>Hello</div>'); // Hello


function htmlParse ($tag, $str) {
    return preg_replace("~<({$tag})[^>]*>([^<]+)</\\1>~", '$2', $str);
}
```